# Send email without page refresh PHP AJAX. The email.php sends email action is in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I want to send it with AJAX. Where am I going wrong with this? The error I get is:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.send @ jquery.min.js:4

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit-email").click(function(event) {
    var email = document.getElementById('mail').value;
    var message = document.getElementById('message').value;
    var dataString = {
      "mail": email,
      "message": message
    }

    $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "controller/email.php",
      data: dataString,
      success: function(html) {
        alert('Success!');
      }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="email" name="mail" id="mail" required="required" class="form" placeholder="Email" />
  <input type="hidden" name="message" id="message" value="test value" />
  <button type="submit" id="submit-email" name="submit" class="submit-email">Send Message</button>
</form>
```

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']) ){ 

$youremail = 'hello@blahblah.net';   
$user_email = $_POST['mail'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$and = 'blahblah.net';
$body = "You requested we email the following to you: $message. Regards, Team";

$headers = "From: $youremail"; 

mail($user_email, 'blahblah.net', $body, $headers ); 

}

$newURL = '../index-open.php';
header('Location: '.$newURL);


?>
```

Comment: Are you saying the page refreshes? Because it won't given the JS in your question (due to `event.preventDefault()`). Also, that error has nothing to do with the code shown as it's warning about a synchronous request, yet the code you're using is async - unless you've set `async: false` in a global AJAX setting, in which case just remove that property.

Comment: use FormData() instated of object data

Comment: @Rory McCrossan I did not touch the ajax settings and I believe by default is true. Any idea how to check this? It does not refresh since editing it with Zeeshan's suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Try this:

It may help.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var email = document.getElementById('mail').value;
    var message = document.getElementById('message').value;
    var dataString = {
      "mail": email,
      "message": message
    }

    $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "controller/email.php",
      data: dataString,
      success: function(html) {
        alert('Success!');
      }
    });

  });
});
```

Comment: thanks, although it does not send the email, it does show the alert.

Comment: In which case your JS is sending the request correctly and the issue is now in your `email.php` file. You need to debug that

Comment: Oh so I'm just using the mail() in php `<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']) ){ 

$youremail = 'hello@blahblah.net';   
$user_email = $_POST[mail];
         
$stand = 'blahblah.net';
$body = "You requested we email the following to you: $_POST[message]. Regards, Team";
        
$headers = "From: $youremail"; 
    
mail($user_email, 'blahblah.net', $body, $headers ); 
            
}
        
$newURL = '../index-open.php';
header('Location: '.$newURL);
   

?>`

Comment: @technicalDifficulties The`$_POST` variable is an associative array and you need to access its properties with a string, ie add quotes: `$_POST['mail']` and `$_POST['message']`.

Comment: @Quangdao Nguyen thanks, I have changed and edits the post. Did not even notice because with the HTML form it send. For some reason its still not sending by Ajax though.

Comment: Try this mail.php code:
------------------------

<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) ){ 
        $youremail = "hello@blahblah.net"; 
        $user_email = $_POST['mail']; 
        $stand = "blahblah.net"; 
        $body = "You requested we email the following to you: ".$_POST['message']." Regards, Team"; 
        $headers = "From: " . $youremail; 
        if(mail($user_email, 'blahblah.net', $body, $headers )){
            echo "Success";
        } else{
            echo "Failed";
        }
    } 
    //$newURL = '../index-open.php'; 
    //header('Location: '.$newURL);
?>